# Why does the Chrome icon flash briefly when loading some web pages?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I created the following simple `html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>This is a test.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="500" height="400">  
            <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open it in my browser --
Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit) -- the Chrome icon below flashes briefly:

[image: weird flash]

(It's blurry since it's a screenshot from a QuickTime Player screen recording.)

Any clue what's causing this and/or how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the icon of the HTML file you're opening:

[image]

The Finder briefly displays a "zooming" animation when a file is opened, using the icon of the file. This behavior is unique to opening an HTML file from the Finder; it won't happen if you open the file in Chrome's "Open" dialog, or view it as an actual web page.

Comment: SO glad to have that mystery solved. It was so unsettling; I thought it must be due to an error in my code.